# How to improve performance of mktime?

Tags: c++, linux, mktime

I find mktime cost too much time on `__tz_convert` which will read `/etc/localtime` every time to get current timezone.

However, if we assume timezone never change, if only take one call to `__tz_convert` to get current timezone, which I think can reduce much time.

However, I wonder how to achieve this? There are no field in `std::tm` that I can put my timezone into. And I do not want to re-implement `mktime` from scratch, because seems it has lots of corner case, such as DST.

---

**EDIT**

... OR is it safe to just call `__mktime_internal` with a special `__localtime_r` that does nothing?

---

**EDIT2**

I think I may wrong about why mktime is slow in my case.

In my benchmark, most time are cost in `__tz_convert`, for a lock `__libc_lock_lock (tzset_lock);`. So maybe it is not related to `cat /etc/localtime`?

[image]

Comment: Wait for C++20 and use new and improved C++ timezone library?

Comment: Did you use a profiler to check that this is an actual performance bottleneck? According to `strace`, on my Arch Linux system, `/etc/localtime` is only _read_ once. Subsequent calls to `mktime` only trigger an `newfstatat` system call, presumably to check whether the file's modified timestamp has changed. If you call `mktime` frequently, the kernel will have this information cached, so there will be no disk access, only the overhead of the system call.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I have a benchmark which shows there are too much time cost in `__tz_convert`. That function will check `/etc/localtime` according to my searching(Maybe this searching is not correct, I have not checked that).

Comment: "*...is it safe to just call `__`*" - no, names starting with a double underscore are reserved for implementation and subject to change without notice.

Comment: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/time/tzfile.c#L155 it should only `stat` it on subsequent calls.

Comment: "However, if we assume timezone never change" what happens when your program is running during the night that DST switches?

Comment: Those multiple "Edit" sections don't improve your question, rather the opposite. Aim for one coherent question.

Comment: @Caleth I think this cases are rare, and I can refresh timezone every hour if needed.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Ok, All I want is a solution to improve performance loss when `mktime` is frequently called. However, seems that I make I mistake on why `mktime` is slow in my case, if performance loss is caused by lock rather than sys call, maybe we should find another way, so I made a edit here.

Comment: "performance loss" compared to what? doing nothing? having wrong answers? If you are happy with those, I can suggest a 100% speedup

Comment: @Caleth Yes, what if `__localtime_r` does nothing? Seems will reduce lots of time, I found it does nothing I need here.

Answer (score 0):

I did publish some wrappers on github now which are pretty straight forward implemented and pretty fast: https://github.com/klux21/limitless_times
The API provides the functions mktime_of_zone and localtime_of_zone which allow the specification of a time zone and it's daylight saving rules.

If mktime and localtime are implemented right and the daylight saving the flag tm.tm_isdst is 1 (or 0 during standard time) then there won't be any confusion. If this flag is set to -1 for a call of mktime then the time is possibly ambiguous for the duplicate hour while switching back to standard time and nearly all platforms behave differently. That's why it's better to store times in UTC (e.g. time_t) and to convert them to the users timezone once you need to display them. If doing so then you nearly never need mktime and daylight saving causes no problems at all.